# Symfony2 config.yml use expressions with parameters

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to use parameters in a expression?
I have a setting in the parameters.yml, where I define the currently used environment, and I would like to adjust all the configs accordingly. I.e. I have a database connection and I'm trying to set the ip depending on the used env like this(the ip addresses are obviously not the same as the real ones):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: "@=%param_current_env% == 'PROD1' ? 0.0.0.0 : 1.1.1.1"
```

But symfony gives me an error:

> Something went wrong. Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error
>   occurred during a database lookup.

I'm doing something wrong but what? Is it even possible to use params in the expression, or is the expression itself wrong?

Comment: That's what environment specific configurations are for. E.g. parameters values for env `prod1` should be placed in `parameters.prod1.yml` file. No need for expressions in configuration file.

Comment: i don't know if you can using the expression language engine in the config.yml section. Howenever the syntax is: `@=parameter('param_current_env') == 'PROD1' ? 0.0.0.0 : 1.1.1.1"`  Let me know if works!

Comment: @dragoste: But how to enable the parameters.prod1.yml -file depending of the env?

Comment: @Matteo: Nope. Still the same error.

Comment: Oops I've told you a little lie. You can create *per environment* configs, not parameters files. Anyway, you have two options. First one is to set params values in config files (e.g config.prod1.yml) like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options Second one is probably the right one, which is - `parameters.yml` should be configured after/during deployment.

Comment: @dragoste: I have a ton of different settings for different envs, and I'm trying to avoid configuring these settings during or after the deployment since there can be mistakes in there. I'm only a human after all, and I already have made some mistakes. It sucks big time.
I'm now looking into creating different environments if this expression setting isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question as of Symfony 2.4 - 3.2; The `@=` prefix is used to load [an Expression object](https://github.com/symfony/dependency-injection/blob/v3.2.1/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php#L455) with the string following and can not be dumped by the compiler within the `parameters:` context. But can be used within the `services:` context.

See: The [bug report on github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/9700) for more info.

---

To address your use case; it is best to use environment specific configurations, how Symfony describes in the [documentation for creating new environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html).

Your directory structure should look something like this.

```
app
   config
      config.yml
      config_dev.yml
      config_prod.yml
      config_prod1.yml
      config_stage.yml
      ....
      parameters.yml
web
   app.php
   app_dev.php
   app_prod1.php
   app_stage.php
```

`config.yml` is meant to contain the configurations, services, and parameters available to all of your environments.

All other `config_[environment].yml` files can contain environment specific configurations, services, and parameters. Which change the base `config.yml` values slightly.

`parameters.yml` contains [canonical parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#canonical-parameters) values, and is by default [altered](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/new_project_svn.html) anytime you run `php composer.phar install` *Which should be done anytime you deploy an update to your production environment*. So it is best to leave it as maintained by the `parameters.yml.dist` file and not manually change it.

---

In order to load a specific environment configuration; Symfony automatically attempts to load the `app/config/config_%kernel.environment%.yml` files during container compilation by default. So the environment specific configuration loading already exists.

`php bin/console --env=prod1 --no-debug cache:warmup`

See the [AppKernel::registerContainerConfiguration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php#L48) method.

```
$loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
```

However it is up to you to [configure your webserver](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) to direct to the desired web front controller file. `app.php`, `app_prod1.php`, etc. They tell Symfony which app environment to boot and sets the debug mode.

Copy `web/app.php` to `web/app_prod1.php` and change the environment the AppKernel loads.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod1', false);
```

**Symfony Web Server**

```
php bin/console --env=prod1 server:run
```

**Apache `/web/.htaccess`**

Change DirectoryIndex on line 1 to the desired environment

```
DirectoryIndex app_prod1.php
```

Then change the rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_prod1.php [L]
```

and

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app_prod1.php/
```

Otherwise configure the mod rewrites and disable .htaccess in your VirtualHost file to direct to the desired environment. Which is very subjective to your server environment (php-fpm, NginX, etc).

---

Once the web server loads the appropriate environment, the configuration files can be cascaded however it is desirable.

**config.yml**

```
imports: 
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    form: ~

doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: %database_host%
#...
```

**config_prod1.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml } #load the global/default settings

framework:
    form: { enabled: true } #enable the form setting while keeping all other values

#define environment specific services (usually best declared in a bundle)
services:
    app.my_service: '@service'

#override the parameters.yml setting loaded by config.yml or declare new ones
parameters:
    database_host: 192.168.1.2
```

---

**Alternatives**

1. Separate the config parameters into their individual
   `parameters_%kernel.environment%.yml` files and import them
   individually to their respective environment config files.
2. Use a Bundle [Extension to dynamically configure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html) and load custom parameters.

You can also configure `app.php` to [load different environments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html) based on specific conditions or System Environment Variable. However this does not scale well in production and may cause issues with certain caching mechanisms.

Comment: Wow.. So much information! :D I had forgotten this question and I actually did exactly what you described. I just forgot to answer to my own question. I'll select this as THE answer since it seems to be the same thing I ended up using myself.
I would add some server configuration here to show others how to call the different controllers. I see you have a link for that but I believe it's good practise to have at least something in here as well. ;)

Comment: @GotBatteries updated with some basic changes for handling different front controllers.